# Show that $\Gamma(a -S) = \frac{\Gamma(1-a+S)\Gamma(a)}{(-1)^S\Gamma(a-S)}$

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

If $S$ is an integer and $a$ is a fractional, then $\Gamma(a -S) = \frac{\Gamma(1-a+S)\Gamma(a)}{(-1)^S\Gamma(a-S)}$.

I think that it can be used $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x) = \Gamma(a-S)\Gamma(1-a+S)=(a-S-1)!(S-a)!$, developing the factorials and using identity $\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{z}\Gamma(z+1)$.

However, the minus sign of S gives me trouble. I don't know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Y “fractional” do you mean “non-integer?” Or $0<a<1$?

Comment: Yes. Excuse me, I did not specify well.

Comment: So you meant, $\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-S\right)^2=(-1)^S(\Gamma(1-a+S)\Gamma(a))$? where $a=\dfrac{1}{n}$ for natural number $n$

Comment: Yes, actually. I don't notice that before.

Comment: This isn’t true with $S=1$ and $a=1/3,$ according to Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%28-2%2F3%29%5E2%2BGamma%285%2F3%29*Gamma%281%2F3%29).

Comment: I think the actual expression you are looking for is $\Gamma(a - S) = (-1)^{S-1}\frac{\Gamma(-a)\Gamma(1+a)}{\Gamma(S+1 - a)}$. See the [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) wiki page under the Properties section